# face vs overlays, can face ever win?

Tags: faces, overlays

Some of my modes use [overlays](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html) for contextual information.

However, I have a face that I'd like to always be shown despite any overlays on top of it. Is there any way to have such a "super face"?

Comment: This is not about faces vs overlays. Overlays use faces for highlighting. Please edit your question to make clear that you are talking (presumably) about text property `face` vs overlay property `face`. Presumably the text property you are talking about is the result of font-lock (syntax highlighting). [And the answer is, as @lunaryorn said, that overlay property `face` has priority over text-property `face`.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a whitespace warning face to win, then *use an overlay* for that face, and give it a *higher **`priority`*** value than the overlay you want to shadow.

You can use library [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) to do this. It lets you highlight using text properties or overlays (or both).

Comment: ok, so it looks like I might be able to use Highlight to detect the faces that I want to have priority, and then add an overlay (with the same settings as the face) with a higher priority than everything else. Might have to set an evening aside for that, and I'm a little concerned that it might impact rendering performance in general... you wouldn't happen to know a short recipe?

Comment: I don't know a short recipe. There is no way to make font-lock use overlays, AFAIK. Face overlays are really intended to add highlighting "on top of" text property `face`. They are properties of the buffer (buffer positions) and not properties of characters in the buffer. And overlays can have considerable performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  That'd defeat the purpose of overlays.

I think you must also use an overlay, with a high priority to make sure that it appears on top of everything else.

Comment: that's a shame. the face I want to win is a whitespace warning face, which I want to always win (and it's real ugly) when lines are too long.